# How to Display an Overlay in Camera Preview of a Xamarin Forms Android App

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement an overlay image that is displayed on top of the camera preview of my Xamarin Forms app.

Currently, my app opens up the camera when the volume buttons are pressed, and the captured image is retrieved through use of the MessagingCenter feature. In my Android MainActivity, I open a new intent that opens the device's camera. I can not figure out how to overlay an image using this method.

MainActivity.cs:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "OnKeyDown-VolumeDown", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                return true;
            }

            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                intent.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true);
                App_test._file = new Java.IO.File(App_test._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
                intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(App_test._file));
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "OnKeyDown-VolumeUp", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                return true;
            }
            return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
        }

 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(App_test._file);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
            SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            App_test.bitmap = App_test._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(100, 100);
            string path = App_test._file.Path;
            if (App_test.bitmap != null)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", path); //send image as bitmap to shared code
                //convert captured image to bytes
                var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
                fileStream.Close();
                App_test.bitmap = null;
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

I have found an example that uses a custom camera and displays the overlay by using a SurfaceView, however, I am not sure how it could be implemented in my current app or if that would even be ideal. The code for it is here.

CustomCameraActivity.cs:

```
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private CustomCameraManager _manager;
        private Bitmap _currentBitmap;
        private CameraResult _currentResult;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            _manager = new CustomCameraManager(this);

            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.launch_button)
                .Click += async (sender, args) => await Capture(new CameraRequest
            {
                Orientation = SurfaceOrientation.Auto,
                UseFrontCamera = false,
                MaxWidthOrHeight = 1080,
                CompressionQuality = 92,
                Overlay = new Overlay(Resource.Drawable.document_silhouette_portrait, 15)
            });

            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.launch_button_2)
                .Click += async (sender, args) => await Capture(new CameraRequest
            {
                Orientation = SurfaceOrientation.Auto,
                UseFrontCamera = true,
                InitialMessage = "Info message",
                MaxWidthOrHeight = 1080,
                CompressionQuality = 92,
                Overlay = new Overlay(Resource.Drawable.face_silhouette, 15)
            });

            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.launch_button_3)
                .Click += async (sender, args) => await Capture(new CameraRequest
            {
                Orientation = SurfaceOrientation.Landscape,
                UseFrontCamera = false,
                MaxWidthOrHeight = 1080,
                CompressionQuality = 92,
                Overlay = new Overlay(Resource.Drawable.document_silhouette_landscape, 30)
            });

            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.launch_button_4)
                .Click += async (sender, args) => await Capture(new CameraRequest
            {
                Orientation = SurfaceOrientation.Portrait,
                UseFrontCamera = true,
                MaxWidthOrHeight = 1080,
                CompressionQuality = 92,
                Overlay = new Overlay(Resource.Drawable.face_silhouette, 15),
                ColorEffects = new [] { Camera.Parameters.EffectNegative, Camera.Parameters.EffectAqua  }
            });
        }

        private async Task Capture(CameraRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.preview_image);

                if (_currentBitmap != null)
                {
                    imageView.SetImageDrawable(null);
                    _currentBitmap.Recycle();

                    File.Delete(_currentResult.FilePath);
                }

                _currentResult = await _manager.GetPhoto(request);
                _currentBitmap = await imageView.LoadFile(_currentResult.FilePath);

                ShowMessage("it works");
            }                               
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            _manager?.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            _manager?.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        }

        private void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

            Toast
                .MakeText(this, message, ToastLength.Long)
                .Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could use Custom Render to custom your camera page like this CustomCameraActivity

Comment: Here is an example doing just that: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/